# How to get htmlize.el work for project publishing in Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, publishing, org-mode

I want to publish a project in Emacs org-mode, which contains several .html files.
There are some python code examples in them that I wanna highlight.
But htmlize.el won't do that for me.
Strangely, when exporting single .html  file (using **C-c C-e h**), the code examples are highlighted .
So how could I get htmlize.el work for project publishing?

Comment: Org-mode is a fast-moving target.  Can you give more information about your setup?  Specifically, what operating system you're using, what version of Emacs you're using and what version of Org-mode you're using would help me give some advice.

Comment: Do you have a solution that still works today? Adding `:htmlized-source t` as Dave Bacher suggested does not work for me. I have the most recent version of htmlize.el (1.56) installed, but still in the exactly same situation as you were.

Answer (score 4):

In your `org-publish-project-alist`, set the `htmlized-source` property to non-nil:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("my-project"
           :base-directory ...
           :htmlized-source t
             ...
       )))
```

See the [Publishing action](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Publishing-action) section of the Org-mode manual.

Comment: Thank you. I've made it this way~ :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your code inside #+BEGIN_SRC and #+END_SRC . For example

```
* My python code
#+BEGIN_SRC python
def foo():
  if bar == 1:
     bar = 2
  else: 
     bar = 3
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but it actually doesn't work. Puzzled

Answer (score -1):

using htmlize.el to highlight your code in orgfile, just add codes listed here to your .emacs file:

```
(require 'htmlize)
```

Notes: please make sure htmlize.el in your load-path

Comment: It already works for a single file, the question is related to publishing.